# ASP.NET Core IOptions - Is it Possible to Populate Config POCO Sensitive Fields From Environment Variables In Production Environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am learning ASP.NET Core 3.1 and have managed to get my webapp set up for *development* environment so that a Configuration POCO is populated from appsettings.development.json with sensitive fields populated from user secrets. These are `AccessKey` and `SecretKey` in the listing below. They are populated using *IOptions* pattern and *CreateDefaultBuilder*

**Configuration POCO**

```
public class S3Config
{
    public const string SectionName = "S3Settings";

    public string AccessKey { get; set; }
    public string Bucket { get; set; }
    public string Endpoint { get; set; }
    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
}
```

**appsettings.development.json**

```json
{
  "S3Settings":
  {
      "Bucket": "images",
      "Endpoint": "localhost:9000"
  },
}
```

Is it possible to populate the sensitive fields in the configuration POCO `AccessKey` and `SecretKey` from environment variables when running in **production** environment? For example:

```sh
export S3Settings_AccessKey=accesskeyexample
export S3Settings_SecretKey=secretkey12345
```

**appsettings.json Populates non sensitive fields in POCO**

```json
{
  "S3Settings":
  {
      "Bucket": "images",
      "Endpoint": "localhost:9000"
  },
}
```

Comment: From what I can see here, it might be as simple as using 2x `_` instead of just 1. e.g. `export S3Settings__AccessKey=...`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what will happen.  By default, then environment variable provider will be preferred over the json/file provider.   This assumes your program.cs uses CreateDefaultBuilder, otherwise, you will have to post your startup code.

Comment: @KirkLarkin dot (.) is not allowed in Linux environment variables, so any dot should be replaced by 2 underscores.  `S3Settings.AccessKey`, should become `S3Settings__AccessKey`.   Double underscore will also work in Windows.

Comment: @Neil Yes, indeed. I assume that's why the OP is using `_` but there's only 1 where there should be 2.

Comment: Ok thanks, much appreciated :) Yep, tried with S3Settings__AccessKey=accesskeyexample and that did the trick. Much appreciated :)

Comment: If want to post an answer then will accept it....

Comment: [Environment variables configuration reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables)